# Passing model via Dependency Injection and then setting values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Dependency Injection to pass methods/models around my project.  In this example I instantiate a variable for my model.  The purpose of this is to avoid 'newing' up the model in my class.

However in the past when I've created a nested model I've done something along the lines of:

```
var myModel = new ParentTicket {
   ticketId = "123",
   topic = "example",
   new SubData {
     DateOpened = "01/01/1900",
     Status = "Active"
}
}
```

I like the above approach as I can set all the attributes of a model in a clear, easy to read block.  But as I'm avoiding newing up my model, and instead passing it via DI I can't figure out how to use this block form.  At the moment I'm having to set each attribute on a line by line basis:

```
_myModelviaDI.ParentTicket.ticketId = "1234";
_myModelviaDI.ParentTicket.topic="example";
```

I'm sure there is a way to set the attributes like in my first example without newing up the model, but I've not a clue if/how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth remembering that not everything needs to be injected. I.e. why are you injecting something that looks like it's nothing more than a DTO?

Comment: You don't need DI for this. Btw, most of the time DI makes sense for services, not for every model you have.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did wonder if DI was applicable but wasn't sure,  I'll stick with the way I was doing it :o)

Answer (score 1):

Accepting feedback.  As per advice DI is not necessary for every model that I'll be using.